# Migration of an AWS database failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, cluster-computing, pipeline

Just want to know how to debug the following error. I don't have any other error logs.

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:57:51 Entering phase BUILD

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:57:51 Running command echo Running database migrations...
Running database migrations...

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:57:51 Running command run_result=$(aws ecs run-task --launch-type FARGATE --cluster **clustername** --task-definition **taskname** --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration=**subnet**,securityGroups=**SGgroup**,assignPublicIp=ENABLED}")

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:58:02 Running command container_arn=$(echo $run_result | jq '.tasks[0].taskArn' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:58:02 Running command aws ecs wait tasks-stopped --cluster **clustername** --tasks "${container_arn}"

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:15 Running command describe_result=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster **clustername** --tasks "${container_arn}")

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Running command terminated_status=$(echo $describe_result | jq '.tasks[0].containers[0].exitCode')

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Running command echo $terminated_status
1

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Running command exit $terminated_status

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Command did not exit successfully exit $terminated_status exit status 1

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED

[Container] 2022/09/08 10:59:16 Phase context status code: **COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: exit $terminated_status. Reason: exit status 1**

Comment: What do these logs relate to? Are you using some migration feature of AWS or a third-party or is this the output from a migration script that you have written?

Comment: I am using only aws service, and  trying to run database migration service.